# how to get the newly edited polygon coordinates in google map apiv3

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

i have created and edited polygon successfully and after drawing the polygon i am getting the coordinates of the polygon, what i am looking for is after editing the polygon i am not getting the new coordinates of the polygon(after drag end i am getting the coordinates, immediately the new coordinates should appear as when i draw the polygon happen).

my java script:

```
var map;
    var coords = [];
    var lats = [];
    var lngs = [];
    var myMarkers = [];
    var myPoly;
    function initialize() {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(17.397821, 78.479354);
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);
        addEventListener_marker();

    }
    function addEventListener_marker() {
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {
            coords.push(e.latLng);
            lats.push(e.latLng.lb);
            lngs.push(e.latLng.mb);
            placeMarker(e.latLng, map);
        });
    }

    function placeMarker(position, map) {
        var mark = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: position,
            map: map,
            draggable: false
        });
        myMarkers.push(mark);
    }

    function createPoly() {
        polyOptions = {
            path: coords,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: "#FF6803",
            fillOpacity: '0.25',
            draggable: true,
            editable: true
        }
        myPoly = new google.maps.Polygon(polyOptions);
        myPoly.setMap(map);
        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'click', isWithinPoly);
        markerCoords();
        //removeEventListener();
        clearOverlays();

    }

    function markerCoords() {
        var curLatLng = [];
        curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
        $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        //google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'shape_changed', function () {
        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'dragend', function () {
            //alert("drag end");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'set_at', function () {
            //alert("drag end");
            var curLatLng1;
            curLatLng1 = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng1 + "<br/>");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'insert_at', function () {
            //alert("drag end");
            var curLatLng2;
            curLatLng2 = myPoly.getPath().getLength();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng2 + "<br/>");
        });

    }

    function removeEventListener() {
        //google.maps.event.clearListeners(map, 'bounds_changed');
    }
    function clearOverlays() {
        setAllMap(null);
    }
    function setAllMap(map) {
        for (var i = 0; i < myMarkers.length; i++) {
            myMarkers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }
    function isWithinPoly(event) {
        var isWithinPolygon = google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(event.latLng, this);
    }

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

and html is:

```
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<p id="info"></p>

<input type="button" onclick="createPoly();" value="draw polygon" />
```

---

EDIT:

i am using set_at and other two like this but none of the three events are fired.

```
function markerCoords() {
        var curLatLng = [];
        curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
        $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        //google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'shape_changed', function () {
        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'dragend', function () {
            alert("drag end");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'set_at', function () {
            alert("set_at");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'insert_at', function () {
            alert("insert_at");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly, 'remove_at', function () {
            alert("remove_at");
            var curLatLng;
            curLatLng = myPoly.getPath().getArray();
            $("#info").append("coordinates are: Latitude: " + curLatLng + "<br/>");
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe the events `set_at`, `insert_at` and `remove_at` of the polygon-path:

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly.getPath(), 'set_at',   markerCoords);
    google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly.getPath(), 'insert_at',markerCoords);
    google.maps.event.addListener(myPoly.getPath(), 'remove_at',markerCoords);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your time, and can you please tell me what set_at, insert_at and remove_at will do. cz i am very new to google maps

Comment: i have edited my question regarding the events such as set_at and other two. only dragend event is fired(alert) and others not.

Comment: these are events of a [google.maps.MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#MVCArray) (a polygon-path is a MVCArray) . The polygon is not an MVCArray(but in your updated code you add the listeners to `myPoly`, not to `myPoly.getPath()`)

Comment: Furthermore: you shouldn't add the listeners in markerCoords, each time you call this function you add a new listener. Add the listeners directly after creating the polygon

Comment: @Dr.Molle can you share markerCoords function also?